# How can I change the review build in the App Store?

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to publish my AlertaBlu app for iOS on the App Store. I created version 10.08 for review, but I can't select the 10.08 build I submitted, it only stays in TestFlight.

[image: In the TestFlight is the build 10.08]

[image: But I can't change the last attempt (9.05) by the new 10.08]

[image: I send the version with by this way in XCode]

I don't know if there is a menu or option that I haven't seen, or if I have to do something.
**Can you give me a tip on what to do so I can select build 10.08 and publish the application on the Apple Store?**
Below is a video to demonstrate my doubt:
https://youtu.be/GMdAxoPawrE

Before, the version 9.05 fail by Apple rejection.
So I fixed all. But I formated the MacBook, because the simulator dont work.
Now, I create in the site App Store Connect the revision version 10.08.
In XCode 15 with Sonoma 14.1.1 I send the IPA.
I try to choose the build 10.08, but dont have this option.
I can't too delete the 9.05.
I need to put the 10.08 in the new revision to send to Apple aproval to publish it in Apple Store.
I need someone help me to change the version build to 10.08.